# How to stop linux timer?

Tags: linux, timer

I have a requirement wherein I start a timer and will do a particular task for a certain time. Once the timer expires,I shall set a global variable in the handler. This variable is checked continuously by my process. The process stops once the global variable is set.

But the problem with setitimer as in its [description](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setitimer) is " When any timer expires, a signal is sent to the process, and the timer *(potentially)* restarts. "

How do I stop the timer in my handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `getitimer(3p)` man page:

> Setting  `it_value`  to  0 shall disable a timer, regardless of the value of
>          `it_interval`.